# How do I draw a switch statement in a graphical design?

Tags: modeling

Does anyone know how to draw a switch statement in a graphical design?

For example:

> `If` statement is a `diamond shape`
>
> Loops are a `square` with a `circle` inside....?

Also is there a technical name for this kind of graphical representation? I have searched the internet and Java graphical designs do not seem to come up at all.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526633/switch-statement-in-control-flow-graph

Comment: @NandkumarTekale I have checked the link and its not similar at all to my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As an answer to the second question, such graphical representations are usually drawn using [_Unified Modelling Language_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) (**UML**).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[image: Switch Statement Graphical Representation]

Here's how a switch statement is represented.
A simple Switch Flowchart search on the internet can give you this result.

Comment: This is assuming each case has a `break` at the end.