# Is there any "switch case" in UML use-case specification?

Tags: uml, use-case, activity-diagram

**Is there any "switch case" in use-case specification?**

In the requirements:

- When user select "contract" in combobox, a "contract" tab appears, then user will interact with the "contract" tab.
- When user select "Independently funded", a "Funding" tab appears, then user will interact with the "funding" tab.

How can I specify this use-case in my use-case specification?

Those two "case" will be in basic flow, won't they? Then how can I specify the "switch-case"?

**Edit:** (Because many mistakes what I'm doing, I will make it clear)

I'm not in progress of drawing use-case or drawing activity diagram, I'm in the between. I'm writing use-case specification (which is used to describe a use-case, and will be used later to draw activity diagram).

For more detail: https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=use-case+specification&biw=1280&bih=683&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIn6ujsMDRxwIVC5COCh3aNQGY#

Comment: Do you want to draw a use-case or a activity diagram?

Comment: I'm writing use-case specification, which will then be used to draw activity diagram.
The normal process is : draw use-case diagram -> write use-case specification for each use-case -> draw activity for each use-case

Comment: _Related:_ [How do I draw a switch statement in a graphical design?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22067183/814702)

Comment: Also here is a related tutorial, where on the Step 6 you can see an example of the "switch" statement drawn using UML: [Simple Guide on Creating Flowchart for Switch Statement](https://www.edrawsoft.com/flowchart/flowchart-for-switch-statement.php).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are describing the use case in the notes then write something like

> Step m: User selects ?? from combobox. If selection is "contract" resume at Step n. If selection is "Funding" resume at Step o. ...
>   ...
>
> Step n:  Resume at Step p.
>
> Step o:  Resume at Step p.
>
> Step p: ...

where `m, n, o` and `p` are subsequent step numbers in your scenario.

If you are using Activities with Actions you can use a Decision node from where you have multiple outgoing transitions. Each transition then has a guard describing the switch (kind of a multi-if).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sample activity diagram.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 6):

PlantUML suggests elseif-chains which gives also a nice graph.

[image: example]

Comment: The guards must be enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: Also, the decision node as per UML specs is not hex but quad edged (parallelogram standing on its edge).

Comment: That was not my suggestion. It's from plantuml page. The red lines/yellow background is such oldschool, that I always thought it may be UML 1.x.
I agree, that this violates the UML specs + my aesthetics. But it is sufficient to show the idea

Comment: More or less. I agree that the idea in conveyed. But showing a picture should comply to the standard. Even UML 1.5 states: _The icon provided for a decision is the traditional diamond shape, with one incoming arrow and with two or more outgoing arrows, each labeled by a distinct guard condition with no event trigger._  So you'd better used Powerpoint in that case. You should report a bug at PlantUML.

Comment: "You should report a bug at PlantUML" - this is a good idea! I'm going to look for their bug tracker.

Comment: If you add a remark to your answer about the shown bugs (decision and guards) I'll revoke my down vote.

Comment: ;) Setting up a bounty is effective nudging. *thumbs up*

Comment: Quick tip for anyone who wants to have the diamond-style decision step. Use:
skinparam conditionStyle InsideDiamond

Answer (score 3):

I think this one fulfill the purpose of the cases and follows the UML decision object rules.

[image]