# plantuml - activity diagram: Decision node with three outgoing edges and [else] guard

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

How can I design a Decision node with three outgoing edges and else guard?

what I'd like is - 3 outgoing edges from decision node 'test?'

[image]

```
@startuml

start
:dd;
if (test?) then (a)
  :A;
else if (b)
  :B;
else (c)
  :C;
endif
:wertz;
:dewe;
end

@enduml
```

Comment: Welcome, what have you tried so far?

Comment: thx for your response,

enclosed my example - but this is not working as it is supposed to.. i'd like 3 edges going out from "test?"
`code`
start
:dd;
if (test?) then (a)
  :A;
else if (b)
  :B;
else (c)
  :C;
endif
`code`

Comment: Please add your `plantuml code` to the question not as a separate comment.

Comment: You are looking for a possibility to show a switch / case statement. I don't know a real answer for it but did you look at an Activity diagram like in the answer of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297292/is-there-any-switch-case-in-uml-use-case-specification/32299806 or to the way it is shown in the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067090/how-do-i-draw-a-switch-statement-in-a-graphical-design

Comment: yeah I did - don't think this is the right approach :-(

Answer (score 2):

For that you can use several *else* allowed by the 'old' syntax of activities :

```
@startuml
(*) --> if "" then
  --> [[priority = 1&#93;] "A"
else
  --> [[priority = 2&#93;] "B"
else
  --> [[else&#93;] "C"
endif
@enduml
```

[image]

Note it is not possible to directly use `]]` nor `\]]`, both producing  a syntax error, so I had to use `&#93;` to close the bracket

Answer (score 2):

this is another solution proposed in the PlantUML [Q&A](https://forum.plantuml.net/1041/switch-or-multiple-else-branches-for-new-activity-diagram):
[image]

```
@startuml
start
switch (test?)
case ( condition A )
  :Text 1;
case ( condition B ) 
  :Text 2;
case ( condition C )
  :Text 3;
case ( condition D )
  :Text 4;
endswitch
stop
@enduml
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar requirement for "Switch or multiple else branches" was discussed in the [PlantUML Q&A](https://forum.plantuml.net/1041/switch-or-multiple-else-branches-for-new-activity-diagram), and they suggested the following approach which also worked for me:

```
@startuml
start
if (condition A) then (yes)
  :Text 1;
elseif (condition B) then (yes)
  :Text 2;
  stop
elseif (condition C) then (yes)
  :Text 3;
elseif (condition D) then (yes)
  :Text 4;
else (nothing)
  :Text else;
endif
stop
@enduml
```